# Hide javascript message after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to AJAX/Jquery/Javaascript so please forgive my ignorance.  I found some code to help me display an AJAX window after a form submit button is clicked.

Here is the code:

```
var ray={
ajax:function(st)
    {
        this.show('load');
    },
show:function(el)
    {
        this.getID(el).style.display='';
    },
getID:function(el)
    {
        return document.getElementById(el);
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML to the form:

```
<div id="load" style="display:none;">Loading... Please wait.</div>
<form action="test_form.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return ray.ajax()">
<input type="hidden" name="value1" value="value1>">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The loading message displays just fine when the button is clicked, but never disappears.  Ideally, I would like the message to disappear after the work is done, but hiding it after 10 seconds would work just as well.

I have tried various edits using hide() and setTimeout(), but my lack of experience with AJAX/JavaScript keeps breaking the code.

Comment: ajax functions generally support callbacks that get invoked when data is returned from the server, or on error conditions. Your "hide" logic should go into wherever your ajax library's callback sections are.

Comment: where is the actual ajax code though?

Comment: Is an AJAX call actually being called?? From your limited code snippet, you are not calling an AJAX call.. Instead you are just loading a "loading please wait" and then executing a POST on the form.

Comment: That is correct, and I apologize for the misuse of the term AJAX.  I just want to close the window after 10 seconds.

Comment: Please look up what AJAX is. As of right now, you are not making any AJAX requests - you are simply submitting a form with a dialog box. You should reword the question as it is incorrectly asked at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/DHgN4/1/**

You said in the comments below your question that you just want it to close after 10 seconds.  This will do that.

Obviously I had to comment out your `form` cause the fiddle can't call `test_form.php`, that's why I created a button to demonstrate the code.  It should be enough to get you going.  The main part of the fiddle is this line:

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#load").hide();},10000);
```

That will hide it after 10 seconds using jQuery.  If you don't want to use jQuery then change it to this...

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('load').style.display='none';},10000);
```

I don't understand why you want it setup this way.  Doing a real ajax call, sending the data using the ajax, then waiting and reacting off the response would be cleaner.

Comment: Your solution worked brilliantly!  And I agree, using "REAL" AJAX would be much better.  I know it would be simple, but it seems every time I take a stab at it I wind up wasting hours.  It could have a lot to do with my lack of experience and also the fact that I using the php class TCPDF.  If you can share any links or snippets that would help me with that task I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery to perform ajax calls, start here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/, go from one chapter to the next and look at the example.  I prefer to use jQuery though, here's the API (lots of examples at the bottom of the page) https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and if you just google "site:stackoverflow.com jquery ajax help" you will see lots of simple examples with answers.

Comment: Many thanks for that.  I have been through W3S many times before, but haven't been able to accomplish this via AJAX.  I'm sure it is just me though.  Some added persistence will get me the rest of the way there.  Many thanks, again!